# Retrieve TextField User Entries from SpreadsheetView

Tags: ios, swift

Good day,

I have managed to get my spreadsheetview to work but there is no function to retrieve user entered data from the spreadsheetview, only a function to populate the cells as indicated below. Could someone please assist me with this. The first column in the spreadsheetview is automatically populated using an array populated into labels, that works perfectly. Then the second column is made up of TextFields to allow the user to enter his own data, now I want to save that data into an array when the next tab is pressed and display a graph with that. I have tried to populate the array

```
            func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
        if case (0, 0) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row) {
            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellInfo.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellInfo
            cell.label.text = "STATION"
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemGray
            return cell
            
        } else if case (1, 0) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row) {
            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellInfo.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellInfo
            cell.Rlabel.text = "MAG READING"
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemGray

        return cell
            
        } else if case (0, 1...(GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.numberOfStations)) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row) {
            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyLabelCell
            cell.setup(with: GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.arrayProfileStations[indexPath.row-1])
            //print(GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.arrayProfileStations[indexPath.row-1])
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
            return cell
            
        } else if case (1, 1...(GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.numberOfStations)) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row) {
            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellInfo.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellInfo
            var array = [String]()
            cell.TextField.text = "-"
//            if GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.MagDataEntries {
//                cell.TextField.text = GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.MagDataEntries[indexPath.row-1]
//            }else{
                //Populate the array with user data
                
                //
            
                array.append(cell.TextField.text ?? "0")
                //GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.MagDataEntries.append(contentsOf: array)
                //print(indexPath.row-1)
                print(array)
                
          //}
           
            return cell
//        } else if case (1, 1...(GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.numberOfStations)) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row) {
//
//            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyLabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyLabelCell
//            cell.setup(with: GlobalVariable.sharedInstance.arrayProfileStations[indexPath.row-1])
//            spreadsheetView.
//            return cell
    }
        return nil
    }
```

Here is how the Labels TextField are created:

```
     class MyLabelCell:Cell{
    
    static let identifier = "MyLabelCell"
    
    public let label = UILabel()
    public func setup(with text:String){
        label.text = text
        label.textAlignment = .center
        //label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
            super.layoutSubviews()
            label.frame = contentView.bounds
        }
    }

     class CellInfo: Cell {
    let label = UILabel()
    let Rlabel = UILabel()
    let TextField = UITextField()
    static let identifier = "CellID"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        label.frame = bounds
        label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        //label.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        Rlabel.frame = bounds
        Rlabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        Rlabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        Rlabel.textAlignment = .center
        //Rlabel.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        contentView.addSubview(Rlabel)
        
        TextField.frame = bounds
        TextField.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        TextField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        TextField.textAlignment = .center
        
        contentView.addSubview(TextField)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a couple notes:

- Start a little simpler. Much easier to learn the basics.
- Use `UpperCase` for classes, `lowerCase` for variables / properties

You can accomplish what you want to do by using a "callback" closure.

Add a property like this to your cell class:

```
// closure to send data back to controller
var callback: ((String) -> ())?
```

In your controller class, when you dequeue the cell, you also set its closure:

```
cell.callback = { [weak self] (fieldText) in
    // handle the text
}
```

Back in your cell class, use `UITextFieldDelegate` and when the text field has been edited, send the text back to the controller class:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let s = textField.text else {
        return
    }
    // send the field's text to the controller
    callback?(s)
}
```

Here's a complete example. To test it (and learn from it), add a new `UICollectionViewController` and assign its custom class to `FieldsCollectionViewController`. You don't need to configure a prototype cell -- just set the cell size for the collection view like this:

[image]

That will give you a "column" of cells, each with a single `UITextField`. Each time a text field ends editing (such as tapping into another cell), the callback will be triggered and the data source will be updated.

```
class CellInfo: UICollectionViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    static let identifier = "CellInfoID"

    // closure to send data back to controller
    var callback: ((String) -> ())?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        textField.frame = bounds
        textField.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        textField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.borderStyle = .line
    
        textField.delegate = self
        
        contentView.addSubview(textField)

    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let s = textField.text else {
            return
        }
        // send the field's text to the controller
        callback?(s)
    }
    
}

class FieldsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // just for example,
        //  fill data array with strings from "1" to "20"
        myData = (1...20).map({ String($0) })
        
        collectionView.register(CellInfo.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellInfo.identifier)
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellInfo.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellInfo

        cell.textField.text = myData[indexPath.item]

        cell.callback = { [weak self] (fieldText) in
            print("editing ended for cell: \(indexPath) with text: \(fieldText)")
            // update data source with text from edited field
            self?.myData[indexPath.item] = fieldText
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have learned a lot today, your explanation with the example was spot on thanks again. The only mistake I made was to forget to implement the textField Delegate, that one had me scratching my head a bit. :)